# How to model averages in category theory

Tags: category-theory

As a business analyst, I'm trying to use category theory as a modelling language for information systems. How can I model the following situation? In the category **Set** of sets and functions, there is an epimorphism $f:A \to B$ where $A$ and $B$ are finite sets. There are two real-valued functions $g:A \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h:B \to \mathbb{R}$. $h(b)$ should give the average of the $g(a)$'s for the $a$'s that map to $b$.

This is my attempt:

use the singleton function to map $b$ to {$b$}
use the    contravariant    powerset functor to get a map         $\mathcal{P}^{op}(f):\mathcal{P}(B)→\mathcal{P}(A)$ to map {$b$} to    the subset of A containing the reverse image $f^{-1}(b)$
then I get stuck

Comment: Please use Mathjax, especially if you're doing category theory.

Comment: Your post will attract downvotes unless you typeset your expressions properly using TeX as @Randall suggested.

Comment: Also wouldn't hurt to show some attempts at formulating the solution.

Comment: There is no such function in general: it requires $f^{-1}(b)$ to be finite

Comment: I think it's fine to assume $f$ epi, but you need each "fiber" to be finite for the sum to make sense.

Comment: In any event, the conditions necessary for $h$ to be defined is very hard to even describe from a category-theoretic point of view. Not impossible, just not a good beginning thing to try to do iin category theory,

Comment: "$h(b)$ should give the average of the $g(a)$'s for the $a$'s that map to $b$" is clearer than any formal reformulation.

Comment: I don't know about averages, but expectations can be modelled as [algebras](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebra+over+a+monad) of a probability monad. Unfortunately I don't know anywhere that really spells this out nicely, but you can get some ideas about it from Fritz' paper on convex spaces, https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5522. (This will not necessarily help with your exact question but could be useful to you more generally, depending on what you're doing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set $X$ let $\mathcal{P}_f(X) = \{A\subseteq X\mid A \text{ finite}\}$ be the set of all finite subsets. We assume to have a function $\vert\bullet\vert:\mathcal{P}_f(X) \rightarrow \Bbb N, A \mapsto \vert A\vert$, sending a finite set to its cardinality. Note that the singleton function actually evaluates as $\{\bullet\}:X\rightarrow\mathcal{P}_f(X),x\mapsto\{x\}$.

Now suppose you have a surjective function $p:X\rightarrow Y$ (making each fiber $p^{-1}(\{y\})\neq\emptyset$ nonempty), such that each fiber $p^{-1}(\{y\}) \in \mathcal{P}_f(X)$ is finite. Then taking preimages gives an induced function $p^{-1}(\bullet):\mathcal{P}_f(Y)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}_f(X),B \mapsto p^{-1}(B)$.

Furthermore suppose you have a function $w:X\rightarrow \Bbb R$. Extension by zero gives us a function $w\vert_\bullet:\mathcal{P}_f(X)\rightarrow \operatorname{Map}_f(X,\Bbb R), A \mapsto w\vert_A$. Finally we have a function $\sum:\operatorname{Map}_f(X,\Bbb R) \rightarrow \Bbb R, \phi \mapsto \sum_{x\in X}\phi(x)$, which takes a function $\phi$ with finite support and takes the sum over all its (nonzero) values.

Your desired averaging function can now be obtained as the composite
$$Y\overset{\{\bullet\}}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{P}_f(Y)\overset{p^{-1}(\bullet)}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{P}_f(X)\overset{(w\vert_\bullet,\vert\bullet\vert)}{\longrightarrow}\operatorname{Map}_f(X,\Bbb{R})\times \Bbb{N}_+\overset{\sum\times\operatorname{id}}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{R\times N_+}\overset{\frac{\bullet}{\bullet}}{\rightarrow}\Bbb R.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Multiple elements from $A$ may map onto the same element in the subset of $\mathbb{R}$. There is then loss of information?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by 'extension by zero'?

Comment: I mean taking the function $w$, restricting it to the subset $A$ and then regard it as a function on $X$, which takes $x\in X\setminus A$ to $0$. In this instance you can describe it as $w\cdot \chi_A$, where $\chi_A:X\rightarrow \{0,1\}, x\mapsto 1 \text{ iff }x\in A$ is the characteristic function of $A$.

Comment: Indeed you need a map from $X$ that takes into account the orignal map $w$ and the characteristic function. I should like to summarize like this: $Y\overset{\sim}{\rightarrow}Y \times 1 \overset{p^{-1}\times w}{\longrightarrow}2^X \times \mathbb{R}^X \overset{\sim}{\rightarrow}(2 \times \mathbb{R})^X \overset{average}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{R}$.  The average function could well be replaced by sum, minimum, maximum etc.  Please validate.

Comment: I am not quite sure, what your *average* function does. If you mean the function $(A,f) \mapsto \frac{\sum_{a\in A}f(a)}{\vert A \vert}$, then yes this composite also does what you want.